Change to a different dropbox account in Overleaf dropbox syncronization
I was using the premium overleaf feature to connect it with my dropbox account for working offline.
However, it seems to me I cannot change the Dropbox account, other than the one I used to link for the first time.
I tried to unlink and re-link the Dropbox in the overleaf interface.
However, overleaf will always automatically connect to the initial dropbox account.
Any idea how to "reset" the sync setting?
